# Dialog box won't pop up on click Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, dialog

I want to make a dialog box appear when I click on some text but the way I tried didn't work.  This is what I tried:

```
<span class="showMe" style="color:blue">Show Me</span>
<div id="dialog" title="Lorem Ipsum">
                        something
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.showMe').on('click',function(){

        $('#dialog').dialog();
 });
```

Nothing pops up when I click it and it also is just showing "something" on the page.  However, when I change it to an alert it works.

And while I'm at it if I wanted to put a button in the dialog box would I just make a button in that div?

Comment: What are you using for the dialog? jQuery UI? Did you include it on your page?

Comment: Seems to be working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/o5y9959b/4/ . You might be missing the library files for jquery UI dialog.

Comment: Yes I was missing the library, thank you.  Although do you know how I can fix it so it only says my something text in the dialog box?

Comment: add `style="display: none;"` to the div... http://jsfiddle.net/o5y9959b/7/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery UI's dialog, make sure to include the jQuery UI library on your page.